# Cost function requirements for Monge-Kantorovich existence and uniqueness

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, optimal-transport

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be measures on Radon spaces $X$ and $Y$, respectively.
The Monge-Kantorovich problem is stated as
$$ \inf_{\gamma \in \Gamma(\mu,\nu)} \int_{X\times Y} c(x,y) d\gamma(x,y)$$
where $\Gamma(\mu,\nu)$ is the set of joint distributions with $\mu$ and $\nu$ as marginals.

It seems there has been extensive work on existence and uniqueness in various settings (e.g. if $X=Y=\mathbb{R}^n$, if the cost is of the form $c(x,y) = h(x-y)$, etc.).
Is there a general result stating requirements for existence and uniqueness of the minimizer? E.g. I think if $c$ is lower semicontinuous then there is a minimizer, but I am not sure.

Comment: Have you looked in Villani's book Optimal Transport Old and New?

Comment: @DanielAdams not yet - I suppose I'm looking for a quick summary/intuitive answer.

Comment: Theorem 5.9 (Kantorovich duality)  of Optimal Transport Old and New might be a good place to start !

Comment: Not yet? Seriously? Probably I'm just getting old, but I simply don't get why people on here post questions before even trying to find an answer on their own, which in your particular case would not have been much of an affort since one can find the answer in every reasonable book or lecture notes on optimal transport. (btw I beg one can find the answer even here on stackExchange already)

Comment: @Tobsn Isn't that kind of the point of SE though? Maybe it is a  simple question but I'm not just asking out of laziness, but hoping there is a nice/intuitive answer that may benefit others as well.

Comment: 'Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.' ...quoted from the SE guidelines. So, if you have not looked into the literature so far, I've got to believe, you've not tried anything at all.

Comment: I Agree with @Tobsn here, either way, another reference is the newer book An Invitation to Optimal Transport, Wasserstein Distances, and Gradient Flows by Figalli.